# ref on v-tab-item content is empty in mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify tabs to display two different components under different tabs. The issue I am facing here is that, in the `mounted()` when I try to use the `refs` of the components it just gives me the `ref` of the first component that is details, the general refs doesn't show. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

I have added debugger in `mounted()` and when I do `this.$refs` only the first details refs shows up.

```html
    <template>
      <div>    
        <v-tabs slot="extension"
                v-model="tab_title"
                centered
                color="black"
                slider-color="red">
          <v-tab  key="details" href="#tab-details">Details</v-tab>
          <v-tab  key="general" href="#tab-general">General</v-tab>    
        </v-tabs>
        <v-tabs-items touchless v-model="tab_title">
          <v-tab-item key="details" value="tab-details">
            <v-card flat>
              <Details ref="details_form"></Details>
            </v-card>
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item key="general" value="tab-general">
            <v-card flat>
              <Info ref="general_form" :agent="agent"></Info>
            </v-card>
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      import Details from 'views/details.vue';
      import Info from 'views/info.vue';
    
      export default {
        components: {
          Info,
          Details,
        },
        props: ['agent'],
        data: function () {
          return {
            tab_title: 'tab-account-details'
          };
        },
        mounted: function () {
          debugger
        }
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: @MichalLevý any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because Vuetify is rendering tabs lazily (in other words doesn't render the content of the tab which is still hidden)

You can use `eager` prop on `v-tab-item` to force rendering of hidden tabs. See the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tab-item/)